# How do I fix "Cannot set property of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, html, methods, typeerror, console.log

I'm trying to enact the background color to change for my editable div box when the user presses the button, but when pressing the button, everything except for the background color changes:

```
function saveBio() {

 let biography = document.getElementById("bio-content").innerHTML;
  biography = localStorage.setItem('bio', biography);

 let content = document.getElementById("bio-content").setAttribute("contenteditable", false).backgroundColor = "green";`
}
```

I get the error:

TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined.

I've looked online for a solution, even similar questions in regards to this issue but they didn't really help in what I'm looking for. What am I doing wrong? Why is the console showing it as undefined?

I've even done:

```
let content = document.getElementById("bio-content").setAttribute("contenteditable", false).style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

Despite style not belonging there.

The console returned:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `setAttribute()` does not return a value ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute#Return_value

Comment: `Despite style not belonging there` if you could "chain" such methods, then style would definitely belong there ... i.e `document.getElementById("bio-content").style.backgroundColor = "green";` is correct, but `document.getElementById("bio-content").backgroundColor = "green";` is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let content = document.getElementById("bio-content").setAttribute("contenteditable", false).backgroundColor = "green";`
```

The problem here is that, the following:

```js
document.getElementById("bio-content").setAttribute("contenteditable", false)
```

Will return `undefined`, which prevents you from chaining additional calls.

You can save the element reference and then do your changes:

```
const element = document.getElementById("bio-content");
element.setAttribute("contenteditable", false)
element.style.backgroundColor = "green";
```